# Comparator on list with only null value

Tags: java-8, comparator

The following code return Nullpointer exception:

```
Comparator<LocalDate> c = (LocalDate d1,LocalDate d2)-> {return (d1.isAfter(d2) ? 1 : (d1.isBefore(d2)? -1: 0));} ; 
List<LocalDate> list1 = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
list1.add(null);
list1.add(null);
Optional<LocalDate> lastUsedDate = list1.stream()
                .max(Comparator.nullsLast(c));
System.out.println(lastUsedDate.get());
```

Can someone please help me understand how this can be resolved ?

Comment: The javadoc of `max` says: `throws NullPointerException if the maximum element is null`. If you want to avoid that, you can filter out the `null` elements from the stream, but in that case you won't need to use `Comparator.nullsLast()`.

Comment: To perhaps clarify, the comparator in your example is not the problem. The NPE is not being thrown by the comparator. You could sort the list with that comparator without issue. The problem is that the maximum element ends up being null, and `Stream::max` can't handle that. That method returns `Optional` which can't represent null as a non-empty result. It also can't just return an empty optional because "empty" means "no value", yet there was a value: null. Hence the NPE.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Eran and Slaw for the solution and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78079405/comparator-on-list-with-only-null-value#comment137648779_78079405), [Stream#max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) does not allow `null` value as a result (so does not [`Stream#min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-)).

> **Throws:**
>
> NullPointerException - if the maximum element is null

The Stream API is not null-friendly, so neither `reduce` nor `findFirst`/`findAny` cooperate if the resulting element is `null` (not missing! but really `null`).

You can do this:

```
List<LocalDate> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
sortedList.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(c));

System.out.println(sortedList.get(sortedList.size() - 1));
```

Comment: Or without an expensive sorting: `LocalDate max = Collections.max(list1, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`

Comment: Oh yes, that’s smart.